# rspec: undefined method `has_http_status?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In one of my tests I have written

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(422)
```

but on running tests I am getting

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(422)
  NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_http_status?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x...8>
```

In my Gemfile.lock

```
rspec-core (3.5.4)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-rails (3.5.2)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
rspec-support (3.5.0)
```

what am I missing? Thanks

**Edit**

*spec*

```
    it "returns error response" do
      post :create, :use_route => 'spree', some_id: nil
      expect(response).to have_http_status(422)
    end
```

*rails_helper.rb*

```
require 'controller_spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'


# Requires factories defined in spree_core
require 'spree/testing_support/capybara_ext'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {window_size: [1400,700]})
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5

require 'my_helpers'
require 'spec_helpers/base_helper'
require 'spec_helpers/collections_helpers'
require 'spec_helpers/sunspot_helpers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.include Spree::TestingSupport::UrlHelpers
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!


  #preventing url's from being loaded in tests
  #https://robots.thoughtbot.com/speed-up-javascript-capybara-specs-by-blacklisting-urls
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    page.driver.browser.url_blacklist = %w(...)

  end

  config.fail_fast = ENV['FAIL_FAST'] || false
  config.include Spree::TestingSupport::ControllerRequests
  config.include BaseHelper
end
```

Comment: strange error, but you can always resort to `expect(response.status).to eq(200)`

Comment: Something is weird in your setup since you are missing the RSpec matchers. Specifically [RSpec::Rails::Matchers::HaveHttpStatus](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/matchers/have_http_status.rb)

Comment: Can you try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? We need the relevant parts of the spec and the required spec_helper or rails_helper.rb

Comment: Hmm, your rails_helper.rb looks really strange. You should be requiring `spec_helper.rb` and doing `require 'rspec/rails'` to require the core rspec components. If you are using version controler would delete spec_helper.rb and rails_helper.rb and re-run the generator with `rails g rspec:install` as your setup looks totally botched. Then add the configuration for spree, warden etc again.